# Jquery smart checkbox plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jquery pluin that helps with checkbox.

Its basically works this way:
When parent checkbox is checked, all children checkbox will be checked. 
When one child checkbox is unchecked, the parent checkbox should be auto unchecked.

I am looking for a plugin that is smart and flexible to define which is parent and which are children. And it should work for multiple sets(levels) of checkbox.

Thanks in advanced.

Regards
XD

Comment: I figure it out myself. for anyone who may need it, you can get it from http://jsfiddle.net/QqzZA/.
It is simple to use. Just pass in the parent and children element, then it will do its job.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try yourself with jQuery. Here a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/QjDLL/

Comment: it seems like there is no jQuery Plugin doing this.
Have to write one on my own.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

It works amazing, you can also make it fixed, if you don't like it popping up.
You can also group by optgroup

Comment: not really what I am looking for. I do not need a UI widget.
thanks anyways.

Comment: It may not be what you are looking for exactly, but you can start from here and extend, or build your own, because it seems like your requirement is not that common to find ready made components.

Comment: Obsolete link, now: https://web.archive.org/web/20120327235518/http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like that:
http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/